# jQuery Navigation Menu Plugin Recommendations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, menu, navigation

There are 62 jQuery Plugins for menus listed [on the jQuery website](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/44). I want to select one for my navigation menu that has many users and is well-formed. What is your favorite jQuery Menu Plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

superfish: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Superfish